# Updating Primefaces Chart after inserting register in datatable

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have three charts displayed in a index.xhtml representing the data from a datatable.

After inserting a register in such datatable (which is in a List.xhtml), all the three charts should be instantly updated as well, but only 2 of them are updating as expected - the two barCharts, by the way.

The pieChart is updated, but not instantly as the two other barCharts, it updates only after restarting Glassfish or after a long time when the insertion occured.

Why the pieChart is not updating instantly after inserting new register in the datatable? How can I fix this?

Following the code excerpt of chart beans:

```
import br.com.bb.upb.diage.treinamentos.facades.UorPosFacade;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.PieChartModel;

@Named(value = "chartBeanUPB")
@RequestScoped
public class ChartBeanUPB implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private UorPosFacade uf;

    private PieChartModel modelChartBeanUPB;
    //get and set ommited

    private void TreinamentoUPBChart() {

        modelChartBeanUPB = new PieChartModel();

        //get data from database

        modelChartBeanUPB.set("Orçado", orcData);
        modelChartBeanUPB.set("Realizado", rlzData);
        //another settings for the graphic
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        TreinamentoUPBChart();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void cleanUp() {
    }

}
```

Excerpt for **index.xhtml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/include/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="title">
            <h:outputText value="#{treinaBundle.AppName}"></h:outputText>
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="body">
            <h:form id="UPBChartFormId">
                <p:accordionPanel multiple="false" activeIndex="false"  >
                    <p:tab title="pieChart" >                        
                        <p:chart type="pie" id="treinamentosPie" model="#{chartBeanUPB.modelChartBeanUPB}" />
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab title="barChart 2" >
                        <p:chart type="bar" id="treinamentosBarGer" model="#{chartBeanGerencias.modelTreinamentosGer}" />
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab title="barChart 1" >
                        <p:chart type="bar" id="treinamentosBarDiv" model="#{chartBeanDivisoes.modelTreinamentosDiv}" />
                    </p:tab>
                </p:accordionPanel>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

Except of **List.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form id="TreinamentosListForm">
    <p:panel id="idPanel" header="#{treinaBundle.ListTreinamentosTitle}" rendered="#{chave!=null}">
        <p:dataTable id="datalist"
                     value="#{treinamentosController.items}"
                     var="item"
                     rowKey="#{item.id}"
                     selection="#{treinamentosController.selected}"
                     >

            <p:ajax event="filter" process="@form" update="@this" listener="#{treinamentosController.onFilter}" />
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"   update=":TreinamentosListForm:createButton :TreinamentosListForm:viewButton :TreinamentosListForm:editButton :TreinamentosListForm:deleteButton " listener="#{treinamentosController.resetParents}"/>
            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update=":TreinamentosListForm:createButton :TreinamentosListForm:viewButton :TreinamentosListForm:editButton :TreinamentosListForm:deleteButton " listener="#{treinamentosController.resetParents}"/>
            <p:ajax event="rowDblselect" onsuccess="document.getElementById('TreinamentosListForm:viewButton').click();"/>

            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.nomeCurso}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.valorCurso}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Thanks in advance.